# A url with parametar not loading in web view from assets

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview, android-websettings

I have an android web  view its working fine

for when i load

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/knockout.html");
```

but it not works when i load

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/knockout.html#!m49=BR-ES&m50=CI-IT&m51=EC-NG&m52=DE-BE&m53=CL-HR&m54=UK-JP&m55=AR-FR&m56=RU-PT");
```

both url complete fine when work in FF or chrome

Please help me out

my webview has all neccessary parameter link javascript to pluginstateon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, WebView does not support loading from android_assets with query parameters or fragments.

As an alternative, you could use a javascript interface in the page you load to call back into your Java app to get the parameters you require.

Comment: how, can u give any example link?